# How do i improve this job in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

i'm working on this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aharon1377/lichess-games-played-in-the-first-trimester-2020?resource=download&select=lichess_db_standard_rated_2020-02.csv) and i've made some query to understand the data. Before working on it i built a Scala structure in this way:

```
object ChessMatchesParser {

  def parsePlayers(line: String): Option[((String, Int), (String, Int))] = {
    try {
      val input = line.split(',')

      val whitesPlayer = input(2)
      val whiteElo = input(6).toInt
      val blacksPlayer = input(3)
      val blackElo = input(7).toInt

      Some((whitesPlayer, whiteElo), (blacksPlayer, blackElo))
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => None
    }
  }

  def parseMatches(line: String): Option[(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, Boolean, Int)] = {
    try {
      val input = line.split(',')

      val gameMode = input(0)
      val matchID = input(1)
      val whitesPlayer = input(2)
      val blacksPlayer = input(3)
      val winner = input(4) match {
        case "negras" => "blacks"
        case _ => "whites"
      }
      val matchDateTime = input(5).replaceAll(" ", "").take(10)
      val openingID = input(8)
      val typeOfWin: Boolean = input(13) match {
        case "Normal" => true
        case _ => false
      }
      val numberOfMoves = input(14).toInt

      Some(gameMode, matchID, whitesPlayer, blacksPlayer, winner, matchDateTime, openingID, typeOfWin, numberOfMoves)
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => None
    }
  }

  def parseOpenings(line: String): Option[(String, String, String)] = {
    try {
      val input = line.split(',')

      val openingID = input(8)
      val openingName = input(9)
      val openingVariation = input(10)

      Some(input(8), input(9), input(10))
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => None
    }
  }
}
```

So i have these 3 structures i can work with. Then i did this job:

```
val rddW = rddMatches.
    repartition(32).
    map { case (gameMode, _, whitesPlayer, blacksPlayer, winner, _, _, _, _) =>
        ((gameMode, if (winner == "whites") whitesPlayer else blacksPlayer), 1)
    }.
    reduceByKey(_+_).
    map { case ((gameMode, player), wins) => (gameMode, (player, wins)) }.
    groupByKey().
    map { case (gameMode, players) =>
        val maxWins = players.maxBy(_._2)
        (gameMode, maxWins)
    }.
    map { case (a,(b,c)) => (b,(a,c))}.
    cache()

val rddWhites = rddPlayers.
    repartition(32).
    map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2)).
    groupBy(x => x._1).
    mapValues(_.map(_._2)).
    cache()
    
val rddBlacks = rddPlayers.
    repartition(32).
    map(x => (x._2._1, x._2._2)).
    groupBy(x => x._1).
    mapValues(_.map(_._2)).
    cache()


val rddPlayersJoin = rddBlacks.
    join(rddWhites).
    mapValues { case (elo1, elo2) => elo1 ++ elo2 }.
    join(rddW).
    repartition(32).
    mapValues { case (eloList, wins) => 
        ((eloList.sum / eloList.size, (eloList.max - eloList.min)), wins) 
    }.cache()
```

It basically finds the winner for each game mode and gathers average elo, variation of elo and number of wins. It works, but i have some concern on how i have written the things, could i have done a better optimization? maybe using broadcast variables? Please i have to discuss this tomorrow and i need to know possible ways to improve this code.

Thank you!

Comment: You posted same question twice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76483565/how-to-optimize-improve-this-spark-job-in-scala